# Extracting string with known pattern

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a field with a string like this     1742,7572,8761,,J73846,,00000628475,w738

I need all the numbers after the 5 zero's before the comma.

So the pattern is delete the beginning until the sixth comma. Then extract the next 11 digits.

Can't use left function because the length of the other digits are not always the same

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on to a solution.

Used instr to find the start of "00000"

Then used mid to tell it 12 char after that start.